# python3.5: serial port reading gives error

Tags: python

While reading serial port from COM4 port using python, i get the following error:

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
F:\Invsense\motion_driver_6.12\eMPL-pythonclient>python.exe eMPL-client.py 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "eMPL-client.py", line 543, in <module>
data_delegate = data)
File "eMPL-client.py", line 23, in __init__
self.s = serial.Serial(port,115200)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-
 packages\pyserial-3.1.1-py3.5.egg\serial\serialwin32.py", line 31, in   __init__
```

File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-
   packages\pyserial-3.1.1-py3.5.egg\serial\serialutil.py", line 162, in **init**
   File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-
   packages\pyserial-3.1.1-py3.5.egg\serial\serialutil.py", line 206, in port
   ValueError: "port" must be None or a string, not

F:\Invsense\motion_driver_6.12\eMPL-pythonclient>

---

This error is coming from serialutil.py. Can you please help me to resolve this problem. I checked COM4 port seperately using putty tool and it worked fine.

Regards
Vinay

Comment: Is it possible you entered `4` instead of `'COM4'` as the port?

Comment: or you somehow set the port to `int`?

Comment: I tried COM4 also , but that also gave same erro:
I am new to python. i am using this utility for UART prints.

This is how code looks :
class eMPL_packet_reader:

    def __init__(self, port, quat_delegate=None, debug_delegate=None, data_delegate=None ):

        self.s = serial.Serial(port,115200)

        self.s.setTimeout(0.1)

        self.s.setWriteTimeout(0.2)

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: Added code in original post.

Comment: Your comport is calculated as `comport = int(sys.argv[1]) - 1` This will be an int, you need a string. Don't do any argument mangling and just run `program COM4` and use `argv[1]` as the port.

Comment: Thanks Klaus. That helps. I added code now as , comport=sys.argv[1].

Comment: Where is the code?  I can only see a mangled traceback?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Invensense python script.

1. Open eMPL-client.py in text editor and search for the line: `comport = int(sys.argv[1]) - 1`
2. change it to: `comport = sys.argv[1]`

The script was trying to cast the string 'COM4' into an integer before passing it to the serial function, which wants a string anyway. I think maybe they were using an old version of pyserial because there are some other errors in the script.

3. Comment out (or delete) these lines:

   ```
   self.s.setTimeout(0.1)
   self.s.setWriteTimeout(0.2)
   ```
4. Run the client with `python eMPL-client.py COM4`

After all this my python client is showing the MPU data correctly. I hope this isn't too late!